# Proving The Existence Of Limits

Tags: calculus

Consider a non - constant function $f(x)$ increasing and bounded on the interval $(c, c+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$ then prove that $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)$$ exists and is equal to the least lower bound $m$.
$$$$As the function is monotonic so it cannot wildly oscillate near the point $x=c$ as it will violate the one - one property. Also the function cannot have infinite limit as it is bounded in the neighbourhood of $c$.So all the reasons for the non - existence of the limit are removed. So the limit of the function exists at the point $x=c$. Now as $m$ is the least lower bound so every right neighbourhood of the point $m$ contains some values of $f(x)$. Now consider any $\epsilon>0$, then in the interval $(m, m+\epsilon)$ there exists a point say $y_0$ such that for some $x_0$ lying in some neighbourhood of $c$ we have $f(x_0)=y_0$. Now as $f(x)$ is an increasing function, so for all $c<x<x_0$ we have $m \leq f(x) \leq f(x_0) = y_0 < m+\epsilon$. Now as $\epsilon$ is arbitrary so we have $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=m$$
$$$$Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: Ok but is my proof Correct??

Comment: You roughly have the right ideas, but the proof has to be rewritten all over again way more rigorously.

Comment: What do you mean by more rigorous Proof?